# How to add/remove items in spinner adapter

Tags: android

In my application I have two spinner which one is using same adapter.

```
 Spinner mSpinner1 = findSpinnerView(R.id.spinner1);
 Spinner mSpinner2 = findSpinnerView(R.id.spinner2);
 SpinnerCustomAdapter mAdapter = new SpinnerCustomAdapter(this,List<Food> foodList);
 mSpinner1.setAdapter(mAdapter);
 mSpinner2.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

How could I remove or add items in adapter? More specifically when I select one of item that selected item should be remove when selecting another that items should be removed but the previous should be appear again.

Comment: Keep in a variable the deleted item. When the user deletes another item then insert the item previously deleted(from the variable) in the adapter and remove the current deleted item.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you do the deletion of spinner items this way:

```
foodList.remove(foodList.get(itempostoremove));
SpinnerCustomAdapter mAdapter = new SpinnerCustomAdapter(this, foodList);
mSpinner1.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can change the foodList,add or delete

and use mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() to refresh view

Answer (score 0):

OnItemSelected will be fired by this:

```
this.getAdapter().remove(currentWagon);
this.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
this.setAdapter(this.getAdapter());
```